# nodejs injection of service into another service

Tags: node.js, service, controller, mean-stack

Currently, I have a controller which it populates an array using a service and then it calculates a median of that array.

what I want to do is, instead of having all the logic inside the controller I want to create a new service and I do the calculation inside that service.

this is the controller that I have and it's working.

```
var RefCompanyService = require('../services/RefCompany.service')
var math = require('mathjs');

_this = this


exports.getMedian = async function (req, res, next) {

var mxnRateList = [];
var page = req.query.page ? req.query.page : 1
var limit = req.query.limit ? req.query.limit : 10;

console.log(page, limit)

try {
    var refCompanies = await RefCompanyService.getRefCompanies({}, page, limit)

    /**Median */
    for (i = 0; i < refCompanies.docs.length; i++) {
        mxnRateList.push(refCompanies.docs[i].currency.mxn);
    }



    var median = {
        median: {
            mxn: math.median(mxnRateList),
        }
    }


    return res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: median, message: "Succesfully Calculate Median rate" });
} catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: e.message });
}
}
```

this is the controller after adding a median.service.js

```
var MedianService = require('../services/median.service')


exports.getMedian = async function (req, res, next) {
var page = req.query.page ? req.query.page : 1
var limit = req.query.limit ? req.query.limit : 10;

console.log(page, limit)

try {
    var median = await MedianService.median();
    return res.status(200).json({ status: 200, data: median, message: "Succesfully Calculate Median rate" });
} catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({ status: 400, message: e.message });
}
}
```

and this is the new service, median.service.js

```
var RefCompanyService = require('./RefCompany.service')
var math = require('mathjs');
var RefCompany = require('../models/refCompany.model')

_this = this


exports.median = async function (query, page, limit) {

var mxnRateList = [];


try { // I think this is a problem
    var refCompanies = await RefCompanyService.getRefCompanies({}, page, limit)
    /**Median */
    for (i = 0; i < refCompanies.docs.length; i++) {
        mxnRateList.push(refCompanies.docs[i].currency.mxn);
    }


    /**Calculate median, High, low*/
    var median = {
        median: {
            mxn: math.median(mxnRateList)
        }
    }
    var median = 0;
    return median;

} catch (e) {
    throw Error("Error while calculating Median")
}
}
```

I'm sure that my controller is working fine cause I checked it with dummy data and it passes the data correctly. 
what I think is giving me a problem is this line

```
var refCompanies = await RefCompanyService.getRefCompanies({}, page, limit)
```

in median.service.js, so I'm injection another service into this service, but when I try it with POSTMAN it gives me an error

```
{
"status": 400,
"message": "Error while calculating Median"
}
```

i think the `refCompanies` can't get populate it through the service.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was, I had to declare and initialize these two variables:

```
var page = 1
var limit = 10;
```